# Chart.Js - Chart-geo map is too small

Tags: javascript, django, chart.js

I'm using the module [Chart-Geo](https://github.com/sgratzl/chartjs-chart-geo) to make a choropleth map using [Chart.Js](https://www.chartjs.org/)

It actually displays, but for some reason it's too small. I'm not trying to make a zoom option (using scroll) but just make it proper for visualization. I couldn't find a solution since Chart-Geo documentation doesn't enter in zoom topics.
Seems like it's rendering the entire world size, but as it lacks data from other countries, it's just rendering Brazil.

Observations:

- I'm using the framework Django.
- I'm using [datamaps's data](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/master/src/js/data/bra.topo.json) to get topoJson.

Here is my code:

`home.html`

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}

{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home/home.css' %}">

<body>
     <div class="banner2Div">
          <p>Cadastro por região</p>
          <canvas id="chart4" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
     </div>
</body>

<script src="{% static 'javascript/chart.umd.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascript/index.umd.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascript/d3.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascript/bra.topo.json' %}"></script>
<script type="module" src="{% static 'javascript/home.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock%}
```

`Javascript`

```js
const chart4 = document.getElementById('chart4')

import brJSON from './bra.topo.json' assert {type: 'json'}
const canvas_width = chart4.width
const canvas_height = chart4.height
const trlte_shift = [canvas_width / 71, canvas_width / 28.8];

const states = ChartGeo.topojson.feature(brJSON, brJSON.objects.bra).features;

const chart = new Chart(chart4, {
    type: 'choropleth',
    data: {
        labels: states.map(d => d.properties.name),
        datasets: [{
            label: 'States',
            data: states.map(d => ({ feature: d, value: Math.random() * 10 }))
        }]
    },

    options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
            display: false
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        
        scales: {
            projection: {
                axis: 'x',
                projection: d3.geoMercator()
                .scale(canvas_width * 414930556)
                .center([-52, -15])
                .translate([canvas_width / 2 + trlte_shift[0] * 3, canvas_height / 2 + trlte_shift[0] * 6])
            },

            color: {
                axis: 'x',
                quantize: 5,
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[Image preview of the code render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykpTp.png)